# Batch Apex to calculate rates based on more than 50k records

Tags: apex, batch, query

I would like to calculate rates based on sets of Opportunities returned from a query -- this query regularly returns way more than the 50k limit allowed. At a high level, I know that I can get around that limit by moving this logic into a Batch context. The problem is, I'm not sure how to do it given what my query logic is. I basically have to query all Opportunities, i.e. "FROM Opportunity", but I'm also performing a subquery to grab all OpportunityLineItems underneath each opp.

I've been looking for examples online but I'm not finding any. Does anyone know what the nuances are behind querying more than 50k records for a query that has a subquery in it -- and how this works in a Batch context?

Again, I need to have all the opp records and their child records, *and then* calculate a list of rates based on that *full* list. So I can't calculate the rates in each individual batch per se.

I appreciate any help. If I should provide more detail, let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Database.Stateful and subquery not an issue in batch context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting around the query row limit issue by creating Rollup fields on the Opportunity to summarize OpportunityLineItems. Even though the lookup to Opportunity on OpportunityLineItem is not labeled a Master-Detail relationship in Salesforce, you are in fact able to create Rollup fields to summarize it, which is what got me past my issue.

Answer (score 3):

The QueryLocator that a Batchable class uses is subject to a *50,000,000* row limit, not just *50,000* that you get in most other contexts. Do keep in mind, though, you've only got *12,000,000* bytes of heap, so you will need to do your aggregation in each execute method; you can't store all the records in memory to the end. Also, as a performance enhancement, don't query the children until you get to the execute method; this will drastically decrease the start time of the batchable.

```
public class MyBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {
  public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM Opportunity]);
  }
  public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, Opportunity[] scope) {
    Opportunity[] opps = [SELECT (SELECT Id FROM OpportunityLineItems) FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :scope];
    // Do stuff here
  }
  public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    // Finalize data here
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Thank you for this response! This really helps me. If you have time, could you also show me how this would attach to a Scheduable class? I am looking everywhere online and I can't find a straight answer

Comment: Nevermind, I think I got it now. Thanks so much!

Comment: Actually if you do have time, how would you setup a Schedulable class to call this Batch class? Are there any nuances associated with that? (Like what to set the batch size for example, and does that impact the design/order of calculating the rates?) Thank you! @sfdcfox

Comment: @Cory_16 You can build the schedulable directly into the class: `public class MyBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful, Schedulable {` ... `public void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) { Database.executeBatch(this,2000); }` As long as you're not trying to pull more than 150k child records per execute call, you can set the batch size as large as you want. I'd probably intentionally set it to 2000 (as demonstrated above), since it's just simple calculations. Larger batches generally perform better than small ones, unless you hit governor limits.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense. Regarding child records; I know you said that Database.getQueryLocator has the 50 million row limit instead of the regular 50k limit. With that in mind, when I query the child OpportunityLineItems in the execute method, is that then limited to 50k instead of 50 million? (Because at that point a regular query is being written; not Database.getQueryLocator). I ask because the OpportunityLineItems under an Opp are often like 10 to 1, ie each opp might have ten line items. Does it still get around the limit that way?

Comment: sorry I keep hitting return to do a new line but then it posts the comment before I'm don writing. Still new to this!

Comment: @Cory_16 This is special behavior for the start method. In each call to `execute`, you can only query 50,000 rows plus 150,000 child rows, setting the upper limit for for how many product lines you can process at once. In most orgs, this shouldn't be an issue, unless your opportunities have many thousands of products per opportunity, which sounds like a nightmare scenario to begin with, even 10:1 results in only 20k rows queried, nowhere near the limits.

Comment: @Cory_16 you can Shift-Enter to add a new line, but it won't appear in the comments. That's just a limit of how comments work.

Comment: Thank you that all makes sense, but there's one last piece I'm getting a bit stuck on that I'm wondering what you think on. 

Originally, my logic starts with a User query with a sub-query for Opps in it (ie, a user and all of his child opportunities) -- i.e. "SELECT ID, (SELECT ID FROM Opportunities__r) FROM User" ..... Since the number of Opportunities I'm returning was the original size issue constraint, I assume I have to do a FROM Opportunity query in the Database.getQueryLocator, not a FROM User query, right? But if so, how can I calculate rates per user?

Comment: Because if the first query has to be "FROM Opportunity", I can't guarantee I have all opps under that user... well, I guess maybe I'll have to reengineer this.

Comment: @Cory_16 You can still use Database.Stateful or save your temporary calculations in a database record somewhere. You could also start with FROM User, then aggregate the opportunities and line items in the execute method.

Comment: So could I do "Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Opportunities__r) FROM User]" in the Start method? 

The getQueryLocator is what allows for 50 million records, and the number of Opps in the org is the main issue, (there's ~2k users, ~400k Opps, ~600k OppLineItems). Is it ok  if the Opps are the sub-child in the query?

I know you said that a subquery in the start method would slow performance, but this is something we would do weekly at 2 AM, so would that be fine?

If I'm able to do the start method as User + SubQuery Opportunity, then that would be ideal.

Comment: @Cory_16 There's a 10 minute "start time" limit. I don't know if using a subquery will work in start method in your case. You can try it, but I'd personally just query the user directly, then in execute: `Opportunity[] opps = [SELECT User__c, (SELECT UnitPrice, Quantity FROM OpportunityLineItems) FROM Opportunity WHERE User__c = :scope];` then do your processing there. It's also possible you might be able to benefit from [AggregateResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm) so you don't need to query the children directly.

Comment: Ok, I guess that's what I'm getting at. If I Query User directly in Start, then Execute I do "Opportunity[] opps = [SELECT User__c, (SELECT UnitPrice, Quantity FROM OpportunityLineItems) FROM Opportunity WHERE User__c = :scope];", will that theoretically get me around the limit? Because it's Opps and OppLineItems that are large in number. (to reiterate, ~2k users, ~400k opps, ~600k oppLineItems). If I query Users direct in Start, theoretically I could get all 2k back (batch size limit = 2k). Then in execute I get more than 50k records. Does Execute query still have 50k record limit?

Comment: hey sorry to nudge you, I just noticed that I didn't tag you in my last comment so just want to make sure you saw my last question. Let me know what you think if you have time. Thank you!

Comment: @Cory_16 Execute still has a 50k cumulative limit on queries. You may need a smaller batch. Do some research to figure out if it's really a problem. Also, if you just need summations, you can decide to use an aggregate result query, which can sum a ton of records without using up all of your 50k query limit (each sum row counts as only one towards the governor limit, instead of all rows involved in the calculation). See if [working with soql aggregate queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm) is right for your use case.

Comment: Shoot! I think I just discovered that I can avoid making this a batch/schedule or even using Aggregate queries by just using Roll Up fields. 

I didn't think of it initially because Opportunity Line Item doesn't label its lookup to Opportunity as Master Detail. However, you are indeed able to create Rollup fields on the Opp that summarize its line items. With that, it looks like I've come to a working solution.

But I very much appreciate your help! This was a very interesting conversation and I'm sure it will come in handy for me one day soon. Thank you!